# Use non-native fullscreen window mode in PhpStorm on macOS

Tags: macos, phpstorm, fullscreen

How can I configure PhpStorm to use the "non-native" fullscreen mode? I'd like PhpStorm to be fullscreen (without the macOS top menu bar, etc), in the same window (without creating a new window that I have to scroll between).

The terminal for macOS iTerm2 have this setting. You can choose to remove the tick from "Native full screen windows". When this tick is removed, the fullscreen mode will simply take out all space in the window, without creating a new separate window.

### Native fullscreen example

[image: native fullscreen]

Notice how a new separate "window" is created called "PhpStorm"

### Non-native fullscreen example

[image: non-native fullscreen]

Notice how theres still one window called "Desktop". The iTerm window fills out the whole screen though.

Comment: Please forgive me for the silly question, I am not a macOS user, but how does PhpStorm built-in fullscreen mode (View > Appearance > Enter Full Screen") looks like, does it still have top menu?

Comment: @duck_in_hat I have updated with examples

Answer (score 1):

the only way you can do it at the moment is by adjusting the dock in mac to hide menu automatically and then spread the editor to wider and higher setting
click right on the dock in mac and goto settings and hide menu works for me
i am suffering from same issue lol after i saw iterm2 :P